# Log4j servlet file location

Tags: eclipse, servlets, logging, log4j

I'm using Eclispe to run a servlet on localhost with logging to file. I can't seem to find log file.
I have searched `.metadata`, `Servers`, tomcat and servlet directory and there is nothing there.

The contents of my `log4j.properties` are as follows:

```
log4j.rootLogger=warn,stdout
log4j.logger.package=debug,stdout
log4j.logger.package=error,servletAppender

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.servletAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.servletAppender.File=log${file.separator}servlet.log
log4j.appender.servletAppender.MaxFileSize=5120KB
log4j.appender.servletAppender.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.servletAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.servletAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p %c{3}:%L - %m%n
```

The logging line is:

```
logger.fatal("fatal");
```

I can also see logging to console, which should mean that the properties file is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try finding your servlet.log from with the directory where your eclipse.exe is in.

I also was doing this form of logging and eventually found the file logs in the directory.